# IDE0130 Namespace does not match folder structure warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, namespaces

I am getting this error message

> Warning   IDE0130 Namespace "StockPortal" does not match folder
> structure, expected "StockPortal."

but the namespace is correct. Any solution for this?
Please refer to the below screenshot as well
[image]

Comment: Could you also provide a folder structure of your solution folder?

Comment: @Sasha Please refer to the attached screenshot. The folder structure is shown in the solution explorer

Comment: This seems like a solution structure though. I was curious if, for example, folder names in the solution folder do not match project / namespace names.

Comment: difference  in "StockPortal" and "StockPortal." is  dot in the end, not clear why its like that

Comment: Yeah the dot is the difference. That's why I am asking this question :)

Comment: Have a look at the [roslyn bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55014)

Comment: @SirRufo I have already gone through that page, but couldn't find a proper solution. Please share if you got any.

Comment: Did you also read the [linked issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55015) with the sample project. It seems the issue depends on the VS version you are using. I had checked that with VS **16.11.7**, **17.0.1** and **17.1.0 Preview 1.1** without any issues on that sample project. I can see in your screenshot you have pending updates for VS, so please check if you are working with the latest version.

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you could post us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

It’s just a warning and asking the user to have the namespace matching with the same folder name. This warning can be ignored. It’s recommended to use the namespace matching with the folder hierarchy so that it becomes easy the get the location of file in the folder structure. And when user creates new file inside any folder using VS template, it creates the file with the folder structure namespace by default. It’s recommended but optional.

In your case there is no folder named as `StockPortal` in the StockPortal project and if the file is located in `StockPortal` folder and if you’re using the namespace `StockPortal.StockPortal`then warning will go away.

Buy Program.cs is generally under root folder of source code.

Comment: If you notice the program.cs is not in the folder. It is in the project. So, the namepsace that I have mentioned is correct. But getting an error.
This is how the structure is available for program.cs
Solution -> StockPortal (project) -> program.cs

Comment: It searches project wise, so expecting StockPortal folder in StockPortal project. You can just verify

Comment: I created a folder and added. Got the same warning and then changed the namespace to 
 StockPortal.StockPortal and it worked out. But we can't use a namespace like that. It is bizarre

Comment: @Ameer as I mentioned that it’s completely fine to use different namespace. Warning is just a recommendation

Comment: thanks, but it would be better if there is a way to resolve this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too for a while. I have .NET SDK 5.0.404 installed with VS 2019, 16.11.8, latest.

It is mentioned here:

- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55014

and here:

- https://github.com/edumserrano/dot-net-sdk-extensions/issues/73

The issue (first one) is closed but people still experience problems.

Until it is fixed I solve it by adding the following to the project-file:

```
<Project ...>
    ...
    <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        <NoWarn>IDE0130</NoWarn>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

Hope that helps until it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But you are hiding the warning and I know this method when I was asking the question. Hiding is not a solution, I was asking a solution instead of hiding the warning,

Comment: Ok. I do not understand why the issue https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55014 is closed when people still experience problems. But I am pretty sure this is a "bug" that will be fixed. I mean, the warning is incorrect. Namespaces can not end with dots.

Comment: It's now sort of 'official' that the fix for this bug will [NOT](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55014#issuecomment-1067313565) be backported into VS 2019